# Curl request on Rails 5 API results in ActionController::ParameterMissing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, curl, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm creating a to-do list API in Rails 5, but I'm running into an error that I cannot seem to solve. Basically, I have users, lists and items. Items belong to lists, and lists belong to users.

Using curl in the command line, I have successfully created a user. However, when I try to follow the same steps to create a list, I get this error as seen from my rails server:

**ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: list):

app/controllers/api/lists_controller.rb:15:in 'list_params'

app/controllers/api/lists_controller.rb:5:in 'create'**

After researching for hours here and elsewhere, my thoughts are:
1. My curl request isn't formatted correctly for the belongs_to relationship between lists and users
2. My strong parameters aren't formatted correctly for the belongs_to relationship between lists and users
3. I'm following a curriculum for Rails 4, but since I'm using Rails 5, something is different

Since I was able to create a user successfully, I'll include the user code as well as the list code. I've been racking my brain for way, way too long on this, so I sincerely hope someone can help me out.

---

### Curl requests in the command line

To create a new user:
`curl -d "user[username]=thisisatest" -d "user[password]=thisisatest" http://localhost:3000/api/users/`
*This created a user with the user ID of 10, which I'm using in the list example*

To create a new list:
`curl --digest -u thisisatest:thisisatest -d "list[title]=test list" -d "list[private]=true" http://localhost:3000/api/users/10/lists`
*I'm using bcrypt, so my database uses password_digest, which is why I've included the --digest flag*

---

### Rails/API setup

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do    
  root 'welcome#index'
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    resources :users do
      resources :lists
    end

    resources :lists, only: [] do
      resources :items, only: [:create]
    end

    resources :items, only: [:destroy]
  end
end
```

**db/schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20171005175122) do
  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "body"
    t.integer "list_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["list_id"], name: "index_items_on_list_id"
  end

  create_table "lists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.boolean "private"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_lists_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "username"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
end
```

**app/contollers/api_controller.rb**

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  private
  def authenticated?
    authenticate_with_http_basic {|username, password| User.where( username: username, password: password).present? }
  end
end
```

---

### User

**app/controllers/api/users_controller.rb**

```
class Api::UsersController < ApiController
  before_action :authenticated?

  def index
    users = User.all
    render json: users, each_serializer: UserSerializer
  end

  def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
    if user.save
      render json: user
    else
      render json: {errors: user.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password)
  end
end
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lists, dependent: :destroy

  validates :username,
            presence: true,
            length: { minimum: 1, maximum: 100 },
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password,
            presence: true,
            length: { minimum: 6 }

  has_secure_password
end
```

**app/serializers/user_serializer.rb**

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :created_at, :username
end
```

---

### List

**app/controllers/api/lists_controller.rb**

```
class Api::ListsController < ApiController
  before_action :authenticated?

  def create
    list = List.new(list_params)
    if list.save
      render json: list
    else
      render json: {errors: list.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private
  def list_params
    params.require(:list).permit(:title, :private)
  end
end
```

**app/models/list.rb**

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy

  validates :title, length: { minimum: 1 }, presence: true
  validates :user, presence: true
end
```

**app/serializers/list_serializer.rb**

```
class ListSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :user_id, :private
end
```